# John 8:11; is Jesus condemnation to the Sinners at the Last day Biblical?

Tags: jesus, eschatology

John 8:4-11; KJV;

> 4 **they say unto him, Teacher, this woman hath been taken in adultery, in the very act**. 5 [a]Now in the law Moses commanded us to stone such: what then sayest thou of her? 6 And this they said, trying him, that they might have whereof to accuse him. But Jesus stooped down, and with his finger wrote on the ground. 7 But when they continued asking him, he lifted up himself, and said unto them, He that is without sin among you, let him first cast a stone at her. 8 And again he stooped down, and with his finger wrote on the ground. 9 And they, when they heard it, went out one by one, beginning from the eldest, even unto the last: and Jesus was left alone, and the woman, where she was, in the midst. 10 And Jesus lifted up himself, and said unto her, Woman, where are they? did no man condemn thee? 11 And she said, No man, Lord. And Jesus said, **Neither do I condemn thee**: go thy way; from henceforth sin no more.]

The Spirit of Substitutional Atonement, and Intercession of Jesus before God goes against Condemnation of Jesus for the Sinners.

So is the judgemental condemnation of Jesus Christ at the Last day Biblical?

According to GOD the FATHER'S Love I prefer the Judgemental condemnation to be earthly, rather than the last day.

Intercession of Jesus, may eliminate the consequences of the Sin, or may reduce it.

So, is the judgemental condemnation of Jesus Christ at the Last day Biblical?

Comment: I do not understand why you suggest that Jesus is condemned?  Or are you suggesting that Jesus condemns such people.  Please clarify.

Comment: It's in the Bible, not sure how it couldn't be "Biblical"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by what Jesus said himself about judging, it is quickly apparent that he did not come the first time to condemn. He does, the second time. This is how he put it:

> "I have come into the world as a light, so that no-one who believes in
> me should stay in darkness. As for the person who hears my words,but
> does not keep them, I do not judge him. For ***I did not come to judge
> the world***, but to save it. There is a judge for the one who rejects
> me and does not accept my words; that very word which I spoke will
> condemn him at the last day. For I did not speak of my own accord, but
> the Father who sent me commanded me what to say and how to say it. I
> know that his command leads to eternal life. So whatever I say is just
> what the Father has told me to say." (John 12:46-50 NIV 1987 Ed.)
> (Emphasis mine)

Jesus had not come in judgment the first time, which is why he did not condemn that sinful woman at that time. He told her to go and sin no more. If she then repented and believed in Jesus, she would not be condemned at the last day either. Yet on that last day, condemnation will come to the entire resurrected world of mankind who did not believe Jesus' words (which are the Father's words).

Jesus warned, while on earth, of what the future would be like when he returned again. We await that day. Here are Jesus' own words about the very different role he will carry out then:

> "I tell you the truth: the Son can do nothing by himself. He can do
> only what he sees his Father doing, because whatever the Father does
> the Son does also... For just as the Father raises the dead and gives
> them life, even so the Son gives life to whom he is pleased to give
> it. Moreover, ***the Father judges no-one, but has entrusted all
> judgment to the Son***, that all may honour the Son just as they
> honour the Father. He who does not honour the Son does not honour the
> Father, who sent him. I tell you the truth, ***whoever hears my word
> and believes him who sent me has eternal life and*** **will not be
> condemned;** he has crossed over from death to life. I tell you the
> truth, a time is coming and has now come when the dead will hear the
> voice of the Son of God and ***those who hear will live.*** For as the
> Father has life in himself, so he has granted the Son to have life in
> himself. And **he has given him authority to judge** because he is the
> Son of Man. Do not be amazed at this, for a time is coming when all
> who are in their graves will hear his voice and come out - those who
> have done good will rise to live, and **those who have done evil will
> rise to be condemned**." (John 5:22-29 Emphases mine)

It doesn't matter what you would prefer, or what you think. ***Jesus does not intercede on behalf of those who have not repented nor believed in him***. A day of Resurrection and Judgment is coming, and the New Testament is full of that, especially the last book of the Bible where Jesus tells John the details of his righteous judgment, which includes condemnation of the wicked and those who refused to hear his words and believe them. The need is to take Jesus' own words on board, and to believe them. A study of the New Testament leaves nobody in any doubt as to how **Jesus did not come to judge the world the first time he came, but the second time he comes, it will be to usher in the last day, the Day of Resurrection and Judgment.**

Answer (score 1):

Eisegesis is defined as reading into the text what we want it to mean.  Bringing our own biases and prejudices to the text will always result in a confused and misguided conclusion.  Exegesis is a "reading out" of the scriptures what the scriptures actually say.

Your question assumes two things: the last day in the Bible refers to the end of time; and that Christ's intercession is for everyone.  Both of these positions are false.

The last day is defined according to the scriptures first in Gen. 49:1-27 as the latter days of each of the tribes, the sons of Jacob / Israel, the last of which was Judah who was the law giver until the scepter passed to Christ (vs. 10).  And when did the scepter pass to Christ?

When did the change pass from the law of Moses to the gospel of Christ? First, when he was baptized of John at the river Jordan before His crucifixion in the 1st century AD.  And, finally in full and complete fulfillment at the destruction of that old temple in Jerusalem in AD 70 when He returned in glory to destroy those who sacrificed Him (Rev. 1:7) and persecuted His saints.

In the scriptures the last days were always referring to the last days of the Mosaic covenant and that animal sacrificial temple in Jerusalem which was destroyed in AD 70. It never meant the end of time. It is mankind that have been falsely teaching the end-of-time meaning for centuries. See all of the posts at my blog ShreddingTheVeil.org for the scriptural proofs, especially the ten parts of "It's Not The End of The World' beginning [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/07/18/hello-world/).

Next, the assumption that the intercession of Jesus is for all is faulty.  It is available for all, if... conditional...if we will answer the call to be baptized into Christ, to put on Christ (Matt. 10:32; Rom. 13:14; Gal. 3:27).  Once we are in Christ, covered by His blood then His blood substitutionally intercedes for us.

The unbelievers who have rejected Christ do not have this protection. He cannot intercede for those who have not been covered by His substitutionary sacrifice.  God will judge those who have rejected His son.

But, judgment is not reserved just for the time of our deaths.

> *"and as it is laid up to men once to die, and after this -- judgment,"*  (Heb. 9:27, YLT)

Jesus judges continually, and reproves those whom He loves.

> *"for whom the Lord doth love He doth chasten, and He scourgeth every son whom He receiveth;'"*  (Heb. 12:6, YLT)

> *"11 Chastisement of Jehovah, my son, despise not, And be not vexed with His reproof, 12 For whom Jehovah loveth He reproveth, Even as a father the son He is pleased with."* (Prov. 3:11-12, YLT)

So, Jesus will place judgments and reproofs upon us while we are yet living on this earth for correction and purification, but each of us will face our final judgment at each of our deaths.  If we have been faithful to confess our sins and to repent of them, then God is faithful to forgive us (1 John 1:9). Those in Christ will be passed over out of judgment (John 5:24) and gathered into heaven, and those who rejected Him will be cast out into outer darkness (Matt. 25:30; 2 Pet. 2:17).

Comment: Revelation 1:7 hasn’t happened yet Gina.  All the tribes of the earth mourning because of seeing Jesus would not include Israel & the Romans who destroyed Jerusalem in 70A.D.  Revelation 1:7 also can be cross referenced with other passages of His return in Glory.  Some points you made on the other topics are solid though.

Comment: Yes it has.  All the "tribes of the earth" are the tribes of Israel, and earth was used in the OT for the land or region under judgment.  It was specific to Judea & Jerusalem of the 1st cent. AD.  Not the entire earth's surface.

Comment: Not necessarily true with reference to Revelation 1:7, the proof of that when regarding the rest of the New Testament shows to the contrary your position: 1.) Revelation 5:9 makes it clear that redemption(for example) is out of every tribe, nation, tongue, & people.  All the tribes of the Earth would include this, not merely Israel.  2.) Matthew 25:31-32 shows Rev 1:7 from a different angle, namely all the nations (& tribes) being gathered before Jesus, they all see Him.  3.) Luke 21:7 in Greek is noted by scholars to show more than the Temples destruction being in view.

Comment: Study more... learn the language of the OT, and the Hebrew idioms & know that the "nations" was a current time frame reference to those conquered by the ancient Roman empire and turned into provinces of Rome.

Comment: Where God’s Providence permits, I’d be glad to study more in depth with Hebrew idioms, etc.  However I will leave it at this final note: In Revelation 1:7 there is no explicit mention of Israel or the 12 tribes of Israel as in Rev 7:4.  Israel would be included as “part” of world, but isn’t named “earth” or “land” in that context of Rev 1:7, notably if you compare with Matthew 24:30 which uses the same Greek word for “tribes”(phylai) as in Rev 1:7, as well as the same word for “earth”(gēs) in both verses.  Matthew’s context=worldwide judgment; as is Rev 1:7, since Israel isn’t main idea.

Comment: Do you think that Jesus was joking or lying to those 7 churches in Asia in the 1st cent. AD when He told them He was coming back soon?  Do you think He lied to His disciples when He told them that all those things in Matt 24 would be done in THAT generation?  Please read the posts at my site, esp. Perspective at the top margin to begin to see how it was all fulfilled in that generation.  www.ShreddingTheVeil.org.  He did it all.  We are not waiting for Him to come again.

Comment: No, I don’t believe that Jesus lied, however I believe the Apostle Peter summed up why Jesus hasn’t returned yet: 2 Peter 3:1-14 is the answer.  For the Lord 1,000 years is as one day, & one day is as 1,000 years.  Jesus isn’t slack about His promise to return.  The passages in the gospels about “all these things taking place within a generation is a prophecy about the future, not about the generation within Jerusalem’s destruction.  As I said to you before, the Greek in Luke 21:7 shows that Jesus is speaking in plural form: meaning more than just the temples destruction is in view.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the institutional doctrine is.... but it doesn't agree with the OT apocalyptic judgment language metaphors.

Comment: Do you mind giving me a few articles, books, and the like to get up to speed on what you mean by "OT apocalyptic judgment language metaphors" ??  Not just your website, but other sources from other authors as well?

Comment: Last Days Madness by Gary DeMar, chap. 10 & 11;  The Book of Revelation by Foy E Wallace, on line pdf copy available; Revelation Explained by Kurt Simmons; Matthew 24 Fulfilled by John L. Bray; The Elements Shall Melt by Don K. Preston to start with a few.  They all explain the OT judgment language of suns and moons no longer giving their light, and stars falling... the stars of heaven in the OT were the sons of Jacob (Joseph's dream in Gen. 37) as well as Abraham's promised descendants... Rev is OT language which John used throughout his books.

Comment: I’ll screenshot the references you mentioned to store on my phone, I’ll check em out when I have time.  Are most of those books or online articles?  Some of the things you mentioned sound like allegory, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Most are available at Amazon.com.  Foy Wallace's book is old enough to be free on line.  You can do engine searches on the others.  But, not allegory.  Metaphors.  When the OT says one thing "is as" another thing, God has defined the metaphor.  Prophetic language is ripe with His metaphors.  Such as the  temple which the Jews referred to as "heaven and earth".  So when Christ said "heaven and earth" would pass away, we paraphrase for the Hebrew metaphor and understand the "temple would pass away".

Comment: gotcha on the books/Amazon thing.  On the other hand, does that mean you use Hebrew metaphors throughout all of the New Testament?  Because not all of the Bible is metaphorical.  There are metaphors, hyperbole, apocalyptic language, prophecy, parallelism, proverbs, symbolic language, literal language, historical narratives, etc.  I don’t buy that Jesus meant “Heaven & earth passing away” as related to the Temple, but we can agree to disagree.  I just bought 2 books on exegesis yesterday, 1 of which is related to the Old Testament’s use in the New Testament, I can’t wait to read it.

Comment: Not everything is metaphor.  Most is literal, until you hit the prophesies.  Then you have to watch for the metaphor that God uses to relate the spiritual concepts in natural terms.

Comment: I’ll “chew” on what you said.